# Can't install Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I've been trying to install Visual Studio 2013 on my desktop for a few times but I always get the following messages:

[image]

> - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows desktop the form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the
>     specified trust provider.
> - Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation the form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.
> - Microsoft SQL server 2012 Native Client the form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Generic trust failure is a common error happening in different situations like setting a SQL Server CE connection, installing .Net Framework, etc. (more info at how to fix it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2012/09/07/net-framework-4-update-error-quot-generic-trust-failure-quot-0x800b010b.aspx))

I'm guessing that could be your problem as well.

> Make sure that the following registry key is set on the system:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing\State
>
> The `DWORD` State value is `23c00`.
>
> The above value indicates that revocation checks occur when validating
>   the Authenticode digital signatures on downloaded programs and ActiveX
>   controls.

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me. I double checked if the registry key is set on the system and it is. (I used regedit), but I''m still unable to install it. I don't know why I can't install it for so many times. I also cannot install SQL server management studio as well as mysql. Thank you for your time. God bless.

Answer (score 0):

> This error means that Windows does not recognize the input file as something it is able to affix a digital signature on. It could be that your ISO file is broken.
>
> If you have already tried installing VS 2013 using ISO Installer you
>   must reboot before trying the Web Installer.

source: https://davejsteele.wordpress.com/2015/10/30/visual-studio-2013-express-setup-failed-the-form-specified-for-the-subject-is-not-one-supported-or-known-by-the-specified-trust-provider/

In this link you can download installer

May the Force be with you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me. I downloaded the web Installer, I reboot my computer first before intalling the web installer but I'm still unable to install it on my laptop. I really don't know why I can't solve this issue. I really need this because I'm a student and I have tried to install it many times but I was unlucky, Anyway, thank you again raBinn.

Comment: Hello, I was looking for more information about your problem and another user had a very similar problem , try the following:

Install Microsoft Framework 4.5.1 of the page , restart the notebook and try again installing vs2013.

Good luck !!!!

Comment: Thank you raBinn, I will download / Microsoft Framework 4.5.1  and give you an update if it successfull.

Comment: I just downloaded it, and it say : My installation will not occur.                        -   .NET Framework 4.5.1 or a later update is already installed on this computer.